# puppet code deleted a file, instead of replacing

Tags: puppet

I am having issues with puppet modules, and this modules should replace `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file based on Redhat version. So the issue is, after applying the code, puppet deleted the file, instead of replacing it.

someone please suggest any wrong with my code.

here is the my puppet manifest file;

```
class os_vul_ssh {
    case $::operatingsystemmajrelease {
        '6':{$sshconfigfile = 'sshd_config.rhel6'}
        '7':{$sshconfigfile = 'sshd_config.rhel7'}
    }

    package { "openssh-server":
        ensure    =>  installed,
    }

    service { 'sshd':
        ensure    =>  "running",
        enable    =>  true,
        require   =>  Package["openssh-server"],
    }

    file { "/etc/ssh/sshd_config":
        owner     =>  root,
        group     =>  root,
        mode      =>  '0644',
        source    =>  "puppet:///modules/os_vul/${::sshconfigfile}",
        require   =>  Package["openssh-server"],
        notify    =>  Service["sshd"],
    }
}
```

Comment: debug output of a puppet run might help a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file { "/etc/ssh/sshd_config":
  ensure  => file, <----- this is missing
  owner   => root,
  group   => root,
  mode    => '0644',
  source  => "puppet:///modules/os_vul/${::sshconfigfile}",
  require => Package["openssh-server"],
  notify  => Service["sshd"],
}
```

Might be more going on here, but this is the first issue that jumps out at me.

By the way, you can cleanup your code with this:

```
file { "/etc/ssh/sshd_config":
  ensure  => file,
  owner   => root,
  group   => root,
  mode    => '0644',
  source  => "puppet:///modules/os_vul/sshd_config.rhel${::operatingsystemmajrelease}",
  require => Package["openssh-server"],
  notify  => Service["sshd"],
}
```

and if you are using Facter 3 then consider changing your fact to:

```
$facts['operatingsystemmajrelease']
```

and note that your `sshconfigfile` is a local variable and should be included in your file resource as a local variable `$sshconfigfile` and not global `$::sshconfigfile`.

Comment: Also note that the file resource does not have a default value for `ensure`. so this answer is correct in adding `ensure => file`... https://github.com/puppet/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/file/ensure.rb#L35-L36